# Unity - Scroll Rect shows buttons outside of the rectangle

Tags: c#, unity, scrolling

I have this problem. I'm using a scroll rect to display a series of buttons, but I would make sure that as soon as the buttons (with the scroll rect), come out of a certain area (bounded by a panel), become invisible. to explain it better in the pictures. I would like the visible part of the list of buttons to stop where there is the black arrow, and then I would delete the part where I drew the red waves

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component you're missing is the [Mask](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html). If you look at the [official documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html) for how to use a scroll rect. It'll show you that you need to put an [Image](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html) component (even a mostly transparent one) on the parent container, and the [Mask](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html) component. This will apply a mask to the children that go outside of the parent image. This results in all the stuff that's been scrolled outside of the parent to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RectMask to solve this problem. If you would like to have the scroll area a certain shape (like with rounded corners) then make sure the background image is part of the container object and use a regular Mask instead.